# Map top level maven project to different child project goals

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, pom.xml, parent-pom

Currently we have a maven project structure that looks like this:

- Top Level Project

  - Backend
  - Frontend

The backend project is a java(app-engine) project and the frontend project is a polymer application with custom build scripts.

Both projects build and work great independently. However, they don't use the same maven goals for deployment. The backend is deployed using the appengine:update goal while the frontend responds to the compile goal. Is there a maven way of either mapping the deploy goal to appengine:update for the backend project or to map a goal in our top level project to both the required goals for our deployment?